# Prepared statement on MySQL not working

Tags: python, mysql, prepared-statement

I am using Python 3 with mysql connector

I am trying to run a Select statement on a db, but I am having problems with a prepared statement:
This is the piece of code that does the query

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()

name = 'Bob'
query = ('SELECT author FROM bib WHERE author=%s')
records = cursor.execute(query, name)
```

I tried different syntaxes, but all with the same result. If I try to insert Bob direct on the query string it works, but with the prepared statement

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL 
server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

Thanks

Comment: [params should be a tuple or dictionary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

Comment: Thank you, @Wrikken, changed to (name,) and worked

Comment: @Wrikken: Since you didn't post this as an answer, I expanded it and turned it into a community-wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Wrikken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358679/wrikken) pointed out in a comment, the `params` parameter to [`execute`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) have to be a tuple or a dictionary:

> `iterator = cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=True)`
>
> This method executes the given database `operation` (query or command). The parameters found in the tuple or dictionary `params` are bound to the variables in the operation. Specify variables using `%s` or `%(name)s` parameter style (that is, using `format` or `pyformat` style). `execute()` returns an iterator if `multi` is `True`.

In fact, this is true of any [DB-API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id16) module:

> Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation.

So:

```
records = cursor.execute(query, (name,))
```